# Azure portal active directory write access issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have created a new subscription account with subscription in azure.portal.com. Can please someone guide me how can I get write access for my account. I am getting below access error:

[Access Issue Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McYt7.png)

Comment: Click the `home` button in the upper left corner to try.

Comment: Did you log in with the administrator account?

Comment: In addition, if your account with a subscription is newly created, you may have to wait a while for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It can take a few minutes for the AAD tenant to be created. You might have just tried to go there while its still in process of being created.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new tenant, or did you create an account in the tenant and grant it a subscribed [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) role?

If you create a new tenant, the account you used to create the new tenant with subscription will have the roles of **global administrator** and **subscription administrator**, and you can use this account to log in.

If you just create an account in the tenant and grant it the subscribed RBAC role, then you also need to grant the account the tenant's [global administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal).

However, both of these will take a while to use, it shouldn't be long, you can wait for a while and try to refresh.